# Reshape values from 1 column and attach to existing column name

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3   Col4    Col5
   A        1       1     10      90
   A        1       2     20     100 
   A        1       3     30     110 
   A        1       4     40     120
   B        2       1     50     130
   B        2       2     60     140 
   B        2       3     70     150
   B        2       4     80     160
```

How do I reshape this so that I have the value from Col1 be in the column name of all columns from Col4 and on? My actual dataset has like 20 columns.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
Col2    Col3   Col4_A    Col4_B      Col5_A      Col5_B
   1       1       10        NA          90          NA
   1       2       20        NA         100          NA
   1       3       30        NA         110          NA
   1       4       40        NA         120          NA 
   2       1       NA        50          NA         130
   2       2       NA        60          NA         140
   2       3       NA        70          NA         150
   2       4       NA        80          NA         160
```

Comment: I think the last column should be called `Col5_B`

Comment: You're right, I'm also going to try out your answer, thanks! I updated the question to have it make more sense as well.

Comment: You changed the expected output... Is this really what you want, and not the previous format?

Comment: Yes, because my actual dataset is going to have examples where there is no data found like above. Hope this makes sense! Sorry for changing the answer, hoping the answer you provided still works in this scenario.

Comment: Your expected output seems inconsistent to me since `50:80` in `Col4` originally appeared in rows where `Col2==2`. Same goes to `Col5_A`

Comment: fixed, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gather`, `unite` and `spread` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(var, value, -(Col1:Col3)) %>%
  unite(var, var, Col1, sep="_") %>%
  spread(var, value)
```

**Result:**

```
  Col2 Col3 Col4_A Col4_B Col5_A Col5_B
1    1    1     10     NA     90     NA
2    1    2     20     NA    100     NA
3    1    3     30     NA    110     NA
4    1    4     40     NA    120     NA
5    2    1     NA     50     NA    130
6    2    2     NA     60     NA    140
7    2    3     NA     70     NA    150
8    2    4     NA     80     NA    160
```

Comment: is there a way to not hard code it to just two columns but rather df[,2]:ncol(df)?

Comment: @nak5120 Not sure if this answers your question, but you can use a `-(Col1:Col3)` to exclude all `Col1`, `Col2`, and `Col3`. See my update

Comment: just curious, where in the code is the first column being dropped? Just trying to follow

Comment: @nak5120 It got "consumed" by `var` in the `unite` step. The default for `unite` is `remove=TRUE`, which removes the input columns. You can also set `remove=FALSE` to keep it.

Answer (score 2):

using data table. I am showing solution for two different data posted in the question.

```
library('data.table')
```

**Data-1:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text='Col1     Col2    Col3   Col4    Col5
A        1       1     10      90
                  A        1       2     20     100 
                  A        1       3     30     110 
                  A        1       4     40     120
                  B        1       1     50     130
                  B        1       2     60     140 
                  B        1       3     70     150
                  B        1       4     80     160', header = TRUE)

setDT(df1)
value.var <- names(df1)[!names(df1) %in% c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')]
dcast(df1, Col2 + Col3 ~ Col1, value.var = value.var )
#    Col2 Col3 Col5_A Col5_B Col4_A Col4_B
# 1:    1    1     90    130     10     50
# 2:    1    2    100    140     20     60
# 3:    1    3    110    150     30     70
# 4:    1    4    120    160     40     80
```

**Data-2:**

```
df2 <- read.table(text='Col1     Col2    Col3   Col4    Col5
   A        1       1     10      90
                  A        1       2     20     100 
                  A        1       3     30     110 
                  A        1       4     40     120
                  B        2       1     50     130
                  B        2       2     60     140 
                  B        2       3     70     150
                  B        2       4     80     160', header = TRUE)
setDT(df2)
value.var <- names(df2)[!names(df2) %in% c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')]
dcast(df2, Col2 + Col3 ~ Col1, value.var = value.var )

#    Col2 Col3 Col5_A Col5_B Col4_A Col4_B
# 1:    1    1     90     NA     10     NA
# 2:    1    2    100     NA     20     NA
# 3:    1    3    110     NA     30     NA
# 4:    1    4    120     NA     40     NA
# 5:    2    1     NA    130     NA     50
# 6:    2    2     NA    140     NA     60
# 7:    2    3     NA    150     NA     70
# 8:    2    4     NA    160     NA     80
```

Comment: thanks! Would you be able to make Col4, Col5 not hardcoded and rather just calling the columns from 4 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method with `model.matrix` and `sub`.

```
# construct desired data.frame
dat <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(~Col2 + Col3 + Col1:(Col4 + Col5) - 1, df1))
# construct desired names
names(dat) <- sub("^.*(.):(.*)$", "\\2\\1", names(dat))
```

Here, the formula in `model.matrix` is used to build out your desired structure. The `-1` at the end assures that each level of the interaction appears. Because the function returns a matrix, use `as.data.frame` to convert it. Then use `sub` and the regular expression to alter the names of the interaction variables. This returns

```
dat
  Col2 Col3 Col4A Col4B Col5A Col5B
1    1    1    10     0    90     0
2    1    2    20     0   100     0
3    1    3    30     0   110     0
4    1    4    40     0   120     0
5    1    1     0    50     0   130
6    1    2     0    60     0   140
7    1    3     0    70     0   150
8    1    4     0    80     0   160
```

Note that if you are planning to use this directly in a model, you probably don't want to convert it to a data.frame. In the case that it stays a matrix, replace `names(dat)` with `colnames(dat)`.

Use `sub("^.*(.):(.*)$", "\\2_\\1", names(dat))` to include the underscores.

To make the first part more dynamic, you can create the formula to the `model.matrix` function with a function, like this:

```
f <- function(x) as.formula(paste0("~ Col2 + Col3 + Col1:(",
                                   paste(paste0("Col", x), collapse=" + "), ") -1"))
```

Then try it,

```
f(4:7)
~Col2 + Col3 + Col1:(Col4 + Col5 + Col6 + Col7) - 1
<environment: 0x3d2b598>
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to make col4 and col5 not hardcoded and just go from df[,4] and on since my actual dataset has 20 or so columns?